# create taxonomy in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, taxonomy

I am new to word press, I want to display results on a page which belong to some group from database(I have group column). I think this can be done by taxonomy so I have taxonomy table but I don't know what to write in taxonomy.php file, any idea what is the minimum information that I have to write in taxonomy.php to make it work.

Comment: Say more about what you are trying to make happen on the front end.  Making a taxonomy.php file and having a "group" column in a database doesn't sound like the right way to do things in WordPress.

Comment: I want to display few rows from database which belong to some group on the front end of a page. I have 3 groups G1,G2 and G3 and three hyperlinks for these, when ever a user click G1 it goes to new page which shows all rows belong to group G1 and so on. I tried - baseUrl/my_taxonomy_name_fromtable/G1 but it gives url not found and I have not configured or done any thing other then creating taxonomy page which just display posts.

Comment: I'm just going to point you at a few resources. Sounds like you need to do some reading on WordPress and/or find a plugin.  Here's a wonderful plugin for associating data held in a custom table to a WordPress post:  http://podsframework.org/
Here's the WP codex for custom fields: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields .

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking if you want a bunch of things from the same category to appear on the same page, you should create a category in the Post --> Category part of the admin area of the site.
Then if you want to display the contents of those posts on a page, make a link to that category page in the Menus section of the admin area.
Then if you want to change the way those posts/results display you will create a template file called category-.php in your theme folder and customize that.